# how to fix find() query that stopped working after php-mysql upgrade

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

A few CakePHP find() functions stopped working after a server migration from PHP 5.2 to 5.4 and MySQL 5.1 to 5.7. I am trying to fix them but according to the CakePHP manual, I do not see anything that could be wrong.

I have tried modifying the 'conditions' part that seems to be what is causing the problem to no avail. the function does not return anything.

```
function infoServorder($ev_id){
    return $this->find('all', array(
        'link' => array(
            'Service' => array(
            'QuestionnairesService' => array('Questionnaire' =>     array('conditions' => 'QuestionnairesService.questionnaire_id  = Questionnaire.id'),
            'conditions' => 'Service.id  = QuestionnairesService.service_id'
                                            ),
            'conditions' => 'Service.id  = Evaluation.service_id'
            )
        ),
        'fields' => array('Evaluation.order_id','Service.id','Service.name'),           
        'conditions' =>  array('Evaluation.id' => $ev_id, 'Questionnaire.type_q' => 'TSP'),
        'order' => array('Questionnaire.id ASC')
));                     

}
```

I try to get the:

```
'fields' => array('Evaluation.order_id','Service.id','Service.name');
```

printed on the screen in order to move forward but the function doesn't return anything.

I have a second function that is very similar except for the conditions part involved in this process and it returns all its fields ok.

Comment: Log your SQL requests, look at what this actually generates, and try it manually in MySQL command line.

Comment: Is your `link` keyword is same as `Containable`?

Comment: Are you using DebugKit? Can't remember how Cake 2 works. BTW, tag this as CakePHP 2.

Comment: What is `link`? I see this for the first time, don't you mean `contain` or `joins`? Can't find this in docs either.